# Non linear effects in Poisson regression via splines

Tags: r, poisson-regression, splines

I have fitted this model in Poisson regression, and I need to check for possible non linear effect of age using splines, in R. Can you please help me with the code?

```
glm_poisson_splines <- glm(FALL~GRP+AGE+SEX+offset(log(FU)),
                               family=poisson,
                               data=dat)
```

Comment: You might like to take a look at the mgcv package for that https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/mgcv.pdf

Comment: Or you can just use glm() with ns() --- natural spline---basis, as in: mod  <-      glm(FALL ~ GRP+SEX+ns(AGE,df=4)+offset(log(FU)),family=poisson(),data=dat)    Then remember first library(splines)

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options:

1. Use the `mgcv` package that comes with `R`.
2. Or simpler, use regression splines, for instance natural splines as in the following:

```r
mod <- glm(FALL ~ GRP + SEX + splines::ns(AGE, df=4) + offset(log(FU)), family=poisson(), data=dat)
```